# how to use acts_as_votable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-votable

I have three models in my app, one for posts, quotes & users, right now i have build a liking system where users can like posts, i haven't used any gem for this, now to add voting in quotes model i have used yththe acts_as_votable gem, to use the gem i have added `acts_as_voter` in the user model and `acts_as_votable`in quotes mo everdel, i run the server everything works fine but when i try to like a post(not quotes)i get this error on my console:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 4.7ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `vote_by' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/user.rb:64:in `add_like_to'
  app/controllers/api/likes_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

i have tried many things to solve it but nothing worked, at the end i removed `acts_as_voter` from my user model and it started working again but then voting on my quotes does't work.

**my user model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter, :google_oauth2]
  validates :username, presence: true
  validate :avatar_image_size

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :quotes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :responses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liked_posts, through: :likes, source: :likeable, source_type: "Post"
  has_many :liked_responses, through: :likes, source: :likeable, source_type: "Response"

  has_many :bookmarks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bookmarked_posts, through: :bookmarks, source: :bookmarkable, source_type: "Post"
  has_many :bookmarked_responses, through: :bookmarks, source: :bookmarkable, source_type: "Response"

  has_many :notifications, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :recipient_id

  after_destroy :clear_notifications
  after_commit :send_welcome_email, on: [:create]

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  include UserFollowing
  include TagFollowing
  include SearchableUser
  include OmniauthableUser

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: [ :slugged, :finders ]

  def add_like_to(likeable_obj)
    likes.where(likeable: likeable_obj).first_or_create
  end

  def remove_like_from(likeable_obj)
    likes.where(likeable: likeable_obj).destroy_all
  end

  def liked?(likeable_obj)
    send("liked_#{downcased_class_name(likeable_obj)}_ids").include?(likeable_obj.id)
  end

  def add_bookmark_to(bookmarkable_obj)
    bookmarks.where(bookmarkable: bookmarkable_obj).first_or_create
  end

  def remove_bookmark_from(bookmarkable_obj)
    bookmarks.where(bookmarkable: bookmarkable_obj).destroy_all
  end

  def bookmarked?(bookmarkable_obj)
    send("bookmarked_#{downcased_class_name(bookmarkable_obj)}_ids").include?(bookmarkable_obj.id)
  end

  private

    # Validates the size on an uploaded image.
    def avatar_image_size
      if avatar.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:avatar, "should be less than 5MB")
      end
    end

    # Returns a string of the objects class name downcased.
    def downcased_class_name(obj)
      obj.class.to_s.downcase
    end

    # Clears notifications where deleted user is the actor.
    def clear_notifications
      Notification.where(actor_id: self.id).destroy_all
    end

    def send_welcome_email
      WelcomeEmailJob.perform_later(self.id)
    end
end
```

**my quotes model**

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_votable

    validates :author, presence: true, length: { maximum: 150 }
    validates :quote, presence: true, length: { maximum: 300 }, uniqueness: true
    is_impressionable
    belongs_to :user

    def most_significant_word
      quote.split.map { |quote| quote.gsub(/\W/, '') }.sort_by(&:length)[-1]
    end
end
```

**likes_controller api for posts**

```
# This controller serves as a parent controller for other likes_controllers. 
# Posts::LikesController for example.
# Child controller that inherit from this LikesController should implement 
# before_action :set_likeable, which sets @likeable.
class API::LikesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_likeable
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    current_user.add_like_to(@likeable)
    notify_author
    render json: { liked: true, count: @likeable.reload.likes.size, type: @likeable.class.to_s, id: @likeable.id }, status: 200
  end

  def destroy
    current_user.remove_like_from(@likeable)

    render json: { liked: false, count: @likeable.reload.likes.size, type: @likeable.class.to_s, id: @likeable.id }, status: 200
  end

  private


    def notify_author
      unless current_user?(@likeable.user)
        Notification.create(recipient: @likeable.user, actor: current_user, action: "liked your", notifiable: @likeable, is_new: true)
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you run 'bundle install' after adding the gem? The method the gem relies in hasn't been found by Rails.

Comment: @bkunzi01 yes i have done that

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `likes` is an alias method for `vote_up_for`in the acts_as_votable gem. (see [here](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/1fa72c4ee0a76e69e715bb41208077687d8503b4/lib/acts_as_votable/voter.rb#L8))

If you want to use both I would suggest giving the association `likes` an alias

```
has_many :post_likes, class_name: "Like", dependent: :destroy
```